# There is only one disc with center i0 for which exists a holomorphic bijection from a given domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Let D be a domain which is not the entire complex plane.
and let f a holomorphic bijection to a disc with center at 0, that satisfies $f(z_0)=0;f'(z_0)=1$ for some $z_0$ on a disc.
Prove that there is only one such disc; meaning there is only one radius  for which this f exists.

EDIT: solve it without Riemann mapping theorem.

Comment: Hint: We can write down all holomorphic bijections  from the open unit disc onto itself.

Comment: is this a theroem? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Yes, you can find it in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: do you point out to Riemann mapping theorem?\

Comment: is there a way to use  Schwarz lemma to solve it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_1: D \to B(0, r_1)$ and $f_2: D \to B(0, r_2)$ both be bijective with $f_j(z_0) = 0$ and $f_j'(z_0) = 1$. Then consider
$$
 g(z) = \frac{1}{r_2} f_2(f_1^{-1}(r_1z)))
$$
which is a bijective mapping from the unit disk onto itself with $g(0) = 0$ and $g'(0) = r_1/r_2$. Use the Schwarz Lemma to conclude that $r_1 = r_2$ and then that $g$ is the identity function.